# Allow certain users to see/use hard disk in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista

Is there a way to limit certain user for example an Guest account in Windows Vista Utlimate to see only the C drive?

I have two SATA disks in a computer that I intend to setup in the living room and people can use the Guest account to do whatever but i only want them to see the C drive and not the other drive.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through the registry. Login with the user you want to hide it with and start the registry editor by pressing <kbd>Win Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Type in "regedit" and hit "Run" or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now navigate to the following key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NODRIVES`

If the hey doesn't exist, create it by navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\` and then click "Edit" -> "New" -> "DWORD". Name it "NODRIVES" and enter the correct value as illustrated below by double clicking the key.

This key is a 32-bit value (DWORD). The last 26 numbers of this value represent the 26 letters of the alfabet like so:

```
00000000000000000000000000010111
------ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
```

In the above example, drives A, B, C and E are hidden while D remains accessible. (1 is hidden, 0 is visible)

Drives hidden using the NODRIVES setting are not available through the regular Windows Explorer, in the Open\Save dialog boxes through Windows applications or in "(My) Computer". File Manager and the command prompt (cmd) are not affected by this registry setting and the drives WILL be accessible through these programs.

Comment: It seem like setting up quota is a better options. How about security? How do you set up a user to only have access to folders that he created and not others?

Comment: Well, do as BloodPhilia said. Then right click on drive, choose security and remove all user access to the drive. I did not tested it, but I think in Windows you cannot see nothing because BloodPhilia solution and in DOS you can see only root files, but cannot enter in the folders... "How do you set up a user to only have access to folders that he created and not others?": remove user access from some folders in root...